# How can I stop removing attached class from jQuery function on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a tag wrapped inside li. when user clicked, jquery function is called to change its style

```
 $(".sortLabelElement").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
    });
```

### Css

```
.ActiveSortLabel{
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
background-color:#C6E035;
}
```

I need to keep this class attached to a tag until is clicked by another a tag in same ul list. My issue is when I click on this a tag link, form is post and page reload and in this happening I lose ActiveSortLabel to given a tag.

```
<li><a value="Recommended" class="sortLabelElement sortTag    sortClickedEvent">Our Recommendation</a></li>
```

### LocalStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', $(this).attr("id"));
```

Comment: you will have to use either localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: I have used localStorage which worked but then I need to clear element when I leave page

Comment: I have update code above

Comment: You can use the `onunload` event to do something when the user leaves the page, but that will also trigger when the form is posted.  You could also try posting the form contents using `$.post`, instead of posting the form and letting the page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session storage instead of local storage .

Session Storage expires when browser tab is closed . Local Storage stores physical cache data on your drive with no expiration date until removed with JavaScript or browser cache is cleared .

```
//Example below will clear once browser tab is exited.

    sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', $(this).attr("id"));
```

//FYI Following line of code will clear storage if user switches tab WITHOUT closing.

```
    $(window).blur(function(){
    sessionStorage.clear();
   })
```

Comment: that sort problem only if close tag or window, what about if I go to another page without closing window or tab within same website??